# Operation of a Growler to test armature shorts

Tags: motor, transformer, ac, electric-machine

Can someone explain to me how a Growler for testing electric motor armatures works please? I have obviously read the [Wikipedia Growler page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growler_%28electrical_device%29) but it is still foggy. So the growler unit acts as the primary of a transformer but how does the stator winding (I am testing on a stator) act as the secondary if there is a short and induce a vibration (or force) in the feeler? Also, I need some clarification on the part of the growler that is attached to the stator (but not the feeler and not the primary unit). I am going to see one in operation soon and can update this after I have viewed it in operation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've worked for the last 20 years with DC motors - but have never had the need to use a growler.  My understanding it is used to check for shorted commentator segments.  The resistance of armature circuits is normally very low so it can be difficult to see a shorted segment.

The best explanation I have found is a Youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXQ0heuV6VE

Answer (score 0):

As nobody has answered.  Briefly.
Someone used to using a growler should be able to give a better answer.

The growler has two haws which are coupled by a limb with an inductor on it which is fed AC. The two jaws thus effectively form an electromagnet and a magnetic field appears across the jaws.

Place a  ferromagnetic object across the jaws, such as an armature or stator and magnetic flux flows through the bridging piece and completes the "magnetic circuit.

The flux in the target piece is informally and asymmetrically coupled to the target but as long as some flux is available throughout it should suffice.  Unshorted windings ion the target core produce open circuit voltages. A shorted winding produces a loop linking flux and a voltage is induced in the turn and so current flows. A relatively strong current can occur a the short is often effectively one or a few turns so resistance is low. The current flowing in the shorted turn in turn sets up a magnetic field and an imbalance in the field in that area where unshorted turns do not influence the current in the core.

If something ferromagnetic is brought near the shorted turn it will interact with the induced field. If the sensor is long it will be easier to feel torque on it for a given force and if it is thin it will make a better probe.

---

Wikipedia image

Two laminated jaws that target sits against clearly visible.

Light bulb is probably in series with power feed to provide a current limiting effect if a heavy magnetic shunting effect is provided by inserting the target into the jaws.

[image]